# How to run tesseract OCR using python on Windows?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have all packeges installed.
Heres the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

im = Image.open("sample1.jpg")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')

print(text)
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usama Malik\Desktop\New folder (3)\tesseract-python-master\image_example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pytesseract
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pytesseract import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Image
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: Where does that error happen? Include the complete traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usama Malik\Desktop\New folder (3)\tesseract-python-master\image_example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pytesseract
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pytesseract import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Image
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: Can you [edit] that into the question, in a way that it's in a readable format?

Comment: Its still not aligned after editing.